# Need to get 2 dates from user input and compare them in an if statement

Tags: c#, date, datetime, int

I am asking the user for an 2 input dates e.g going flight and returning flight then I need to be able to compare in an if statement that if the flights are between the summer range the price is 20% more.

All help appreciated, Visual Studio C#

This is what I tried:

```
String firstDate;
            String secondDate;
            double people;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the number of people:")
            people = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double flightPrice = 238;
            Console.Write("Please enter the arrival date (dd-MM-yyyy):");
            firstDate = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter the departure date (dd-MM-yyyy):");
            secondDate = Console.ReadLine();

            if (firstDate >= "15-06-2018" && secondDate <= "15-08-2018")
            {
                flightPrice = 238 * 1.20 * people;
            }
            else
            {
                flightPrice = 238 * people;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

The error is in the if statement (operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Comment: You tried anything yet? If so how far have you got? Try posting some code to help us understand where you're issue is.

Comment: What API is this for? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF? UWP?

Comment: Sorry im new here, This is a C# homework for school.

Comment: Going to edit the post putting the code I tried.

Comment: Number of people should be int of uint

Comment: Is it only for 2018?

Comment: no if I could do it for any year it would be amazing, no idea how to go about that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            string firstDate = "10-08-2018";
            DateTime _firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(firstDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string secondDate = "10-08-2018";
            DateTime _secondDate = DateTime.ParseExact(secondDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (_firstDate >= DateTime.ParseExact("15-06-2018", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) &&
                _secondDate <= DateTime.ParseExact("15-08-2018", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need the two dates as user input first

Comment: The user inputs are the two strings.  I just hard coded values to show all the code needed.

Comment: Thanks it worked!, last thing is there a way to print the number of days in the two dates?

Comment: string totalDays = (_secondDate - _firstDate).TotalDays.ToString();

Comment: Hey, last thing let's say the user inputs a string or a bad date how can I make a while loop or something to make sure the date is correct format? thanks

Comment: You can use DateTime.TryParseExact which will return a true of false indicating if the string date is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the date strings in a specific format, then you can use [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) method of the `DateTime` object to create a `DateTime` out of the string, and then use that `DateTime` object to do the comparison with your hard-coded dates.

We can also use the similar [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to get an integer from the user when they enter the number of people. This allows us to give them a message if they enter an incorrect value (like `"two"` instead of `"2"`) and ask them to try again.

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    DateTime peakStartDate = new DateTime(2018, 6, 15);
    DateTime peakEndDate = new DateTime(2018, 8, 15);

    Console.Write("Please Enter the number of people: ");

    // Use TryParse to get an integer from the user. If TryParse fails,
    // it means they entered an invalid value, so ask them to do it again.
    // Otherwise, numPeople will hold the integer value they entered
    int numPeople;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numPeople))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: input was not a whole number.\n");
        Console.Write("Please Enter the number of people: ");
    }

    // Now we can set the base flight price for the number of people
    double flightPrice = 238 * numPeople;

    // Get the arrival date from the user
    Console.Write("\nPlease enter the arrival date (dd-MM-yyyy): ");
    DateTime firstDate;

    // If TryParseExact fails, they entered an incorrect format, so we
    // keep asking them. If it succeeds, then firstDate will hold the value.
    while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd-MM-yyyy",
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out firstDate))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: input was not in correct format\n");
        Console.Write("Please enter the arrival date (dd-MM-yyyy): ");
    }

    // Same process for departure date
    Console.Write("\nPlease enter the departure date (dd-MM-yyyy):");
    DateTime secondDate;

    while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd-MM-yyyy",
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out secondDate))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: input was not in correct format");
        Console.Write("\nPlease enter the departure date (dd-MM-yyyy): ");
    }

    // If they're travelling during the peak period, increase the price
    if (firstDate >= peakStartDate && secondDate <= peakEndDate)
    {
        flightPrice *= 1.2;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

If you want to be more flexible and let the user enter single-digit days and/or months, you can create an array of valid formats like so:

```
string[] validDateTimeFormats = {"dd-MM-yyyy", "d-MM-yyyy", "dd-M-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy"};
```

And then pass the array to the `TryParseExact` method:

```
while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), validDateTimeFormats,
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out firstDate))
{
```

Comment: Cool. Although `ParseExact` will throw an exception if the user enters invalid input. `TryParseExact` allows you to handle that situation without blowing up... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the date strings to DateTime objects before you can compare them, you cant compare the dates directly as strings.

```
DateTime arrivalDate = DateTime.Parse(firstDate);
DateTime departureDate = DateTime.Parse(secondDate);

DateTime summerStart = DateTime.Parse("15-06-2018");
DateTime summerEnd = DateTime.Parse("15-08-2018");

if (arrivalDate >= summerStart && departureDate <= summerEnd)
{
    flightPrice = 238 * 1.20 * people;
}
else
{
        flightPrice = 238 * people;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this but i'm getting an error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. For DateTime = summerStart etc